# “Both to you and me” & “both to you and to me” & “to both you and me”

Tags: parallelism

Are “*both to you and me*,” “*both to you and to me*” and “*to both you and me*” grammatically correct or not?

> A teacher gave books both to you and me.
>
> A teacher gave books both to you and to me.
>
> A teacher gave books to both you and me.

Comment: Hello.  More context please, or all you will get is a useless comment saying "Yes they are correct".   Why are you asking.  What is the context that you want to use these phrases. Why do you doubt that they are grammatically correct.  Have you tried to find examples of each phrase (for example by searching online)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22both+to+you+and+me%22 ....... https://www.google.com/search?q=%22both+to+you+and+to+me%22 ......... https://www.google.com/search?q=%22to+both+you+and+me%22 ........

Comment: @James K Of course, I found it, but I think they are informal unless they are from bbc or nature kinda place or expertises like you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably use 3 most often.

I'd use 2 if the fact that I received books was something surprising that I wanted to emphasise.  2 is like "not only to you but also to me."

But 1 is also possible. The position of both is slightly odd, and a google search suggests that this is a dated construction.